# Dynamically populate ChoiceField Select within Form/Formwizard

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

First of all, I did my homework and tried finding a similar question :). I have been trying things out for the last couple of hours, but to no avail.

What I'm trying to do seems very simple. I have several forms in a Formwizard. In the first form I have a text-input. In the next step I have a FormSet (but this could also be a simple Form) that contains a forms.Select (dropdown). I want to show the value of the text-input in this dropdown. However, I just can't get it to work. This is my code:

In forms.py:

```
class FirstForm(forms.Form):
    first_point = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput( 
            attrs={
                'class' : 'form-control'
}))

class SecondStepForm(forms.Form):
    dropdown_select = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select( 
            attrs={'class' : 'form-control'
}))

SecondStepFormSet = formset_factory(SecondStepForm, extra=5)
```

In views.py:

```
FORMS = [("firstform", FirstForm),
        ("secondform", SecondStepFormSet)]


class FormWizardView(LoginRequiredMixin, SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'test.html'

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(FormWizardView, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
        if self.steps.current == 'secondform':
            data_temp = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('firstform')
            data  = data_temp['first_point'] 
            print(data)
            context.update({'dropdown_select': data})

        return context

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

        return None
```

And in my html-file:

```
{% block content %}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <table>
            {{ wizard.management_form }}
            {% if wizard.form.forms %}
                {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
                {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                    <div>
                        {{ form.dropdown_select }}
                    </div> 
                {% endfor %}

            {% else %}
                {% for field in wizard.form %}
                    {{field}}         
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            </table>
            {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
            <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}"
            class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
            style="width:30%; float:left;">{% trans "Previous" %}</button>
            {% endif %}
            <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Next" %}" 
            class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
            style="width:30%; float:right;"/>
        </form>
    </div> 
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The `print(data)` statement in views.py does print the value from the text-input. And also, when I change `{{ form.dropdown_select }}` into `{{ dropdown_select }}`, the value on my template changes to the value of my text-input. So that goes all well. I just can't get it to populate the dropdown.

Any ideas how to this? Hopefully Stackoverflow can help me once again (like it always does :)). Many thanks!

Comment: I have a solution for a part of my own question! I am now able to do it for a Form (not yet a Formset). I added the get_form function (will post as an answer for future reference if I have it for a Formset as well). 

However, I get an error for the formset: ```FormSet' object has no attribute 'fields'```. When wrapping my get_from function with an ```for form in formset.forms:``` the error doesn't leave. Anyone any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question and open another one for the Formset problem to make this as clean as possible. For future reference:

I introduced the get_form within the FormWizardView:

```
 def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
            form = super(FormWizardView, self).get_form(step, data, files)
            if 'dropdown_select' in form.fields:
                form1_cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('firstform')


                if form1_cleaned_data:
                    form.fields['dropdown_select'].choices = [item for item in form1_cleaned_data.items()]
            return form
```

As I mentioned in my own comment, this works for Form and not yet for Formset, as I get the error `FormSet' object has no attribute 'fields'`, which doesn't go away when I put the get_form in a for-loop.